# GStreamer multifilesrc never throws EOS

Tags: gstreamer

It appears that the GStreamer 1.0 `multifilesrc` element will not automatically throw an EOS when it runs out of files.  If a `stop-index=N` is specified then it will EOS after N frames.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -ev multifilesrc location="tmp/frame%04d.jpg"  stop-index=20 ! image/jpeg,framerate=10/1 ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! videorate ! xvimagesink
```

Is there a way to have `multifilesrc` automatically generate EOS when the file list is exhausted or otherwise pack the frames into a stream with an EOS?  Otherwise my pipeline just hangs at the end.

Comment: It's strange because by default multifilesrc send EOS when it reaches all files in given directory when you don't use stop-index

Comment: Just peeked in the source and it looks like it should send an EOS.  I don't understand why it isn't for me.

Comment: What is displayed when you arrived out of files (last image repeatedly or a freeze)?
If you generate images with multifilesink with this pipeline:
`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc num-buffers=50! timeoverlay! jpegenc! multifilesink index=0 location=jpeg_files/frame%02d.jpg`
and that you use your pipeline is it working?  
What is the version of gstreamer 1.0 (1.2, 1.3 or 1.4)? You can find this information with gst-inspect multifilesrc.